# How to validate RegExp with an if else statement in react?

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs, react-native

how to alert a user if the user types a symbol into a text input in react?
I tried this

```
textChange = () => {
   if (this.state.texts == new RegExp(/[^a-zA-Z\s]/) ) {
       alert("No symbols allowed")
   }
}
```

but noting is alerting when a symbol is type

Comment: Try `if( new RegExp(/[^a-zA-Z\s]/).test(this.state.texts) )`

Comment: Or `/[^a-zA-Z\s]/.test(this.state.texts)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of comparing the equality of string with the regex object, you need to use [`test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) method, which returns a boolean value based on the passed string matching pattern or not

```
textChange = () => {
   if (/[^a-zA-Z\s]/.test(this.state.text) ) {
      alert("No symbols allowed")
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `test` or `match` methods,

```js
textChange = () => {
   if (/[^a-zA-Z\s]/.test(this.state.text) ) {
      alert("No symbols allowed")
   }
}
```

**or**

```
textChange = () => {
   if (this.state.text.match(/[^a-zA-Z\s]/) !== null) {
      alert("No symbols allowed")
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use text method of javascript to validate using regular expression.

```
textChange =  () => {

  const expression = /[^a-zA-Z\s]/;
  var notValid = expression.test(String(this.state.texts));
  // notValid will be true if entered text does'nt match the expression

  if(notValid){
    alert("No symbols allowed");
  }else{
    //Valid value
  }


}
```